# Django app on apache server with VPS

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I've installed mod_wsgi on my apache server.

And when I configure WSGIScriptAlias to hello.wsgi to test, it works.

But to my Django wsgi.py, it gives 500.

In error log it says 'End of script outpt before headers: wsgi.py'

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

The mod_wsgi daemon process is most likely crashing. For a solution, see:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Thuis can occur if using C extensions for Python that aren't implemented so as to work properly in Python sub interpreters.